# Fixed points of fixed-point combinator?

Tags: lambda-calculus, fixed-points

A fixed point `f` of a fixed-point combinator would be a function that has itself as a fixed point: `f(f) = f`. The only such function I could come up with is `id`, which by definition has the *apparently* stronger property that `id(x) = x` for *all* `x`. Equivalently, everything is a fixed point of `id`.

My question is: is this actually a stronger property (in untyped lambda calculus), or is `id` the only function with `f(f) = f`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "$=$" you mean $\beta$-equality, then the answer is yes, $MX=X$ for all $X$ is a stronger property than $MM=M$.

For example, let
$$A := \lambda a.aa(aa)$$
(to save parentheses, I am using the standard left-associative notation for application; in your notation, the above term would be $\lambda a.a(a)(a(a))$) and take
$$M := AA.$$
We clearly have $M\to MM$ and therefore $MM=M$.  On the other hand, for any normal form $N$, $MN\neq N$, because $MN$ does not normalize (in fact, $M$ does not have a head normal form).

Comment: Thanks so much for the elegant counter-example. Do you know if the same would hold when only considering normalizing terms? I think it's an important restriction because a normalizing term is meaningful as a function and we could see how it differs semantically from the identity.

Comment: It's easy to see that $MM=M$ for $M$ normalizable implies that $NN\to^\ast N$ where $N$ is the normal form of $M$.  I can't quickly come up with an example of normal term different from the identity which reduces to itself when applied to itself, but I'm not convinced it does not exist...  I honestly don't know!